# How do I match my road data with a Mapbox dataset?

Tags: web-mapping, mapbox, streets

I made an app that detects how bumpy roads are but I only know the road name and zipcode. Is there a way for me to layer this on top of a map?

For example, in my database, Main Street in zipcode 01234 has a bump score of -24, I'd like to append that onto the map so that I can show Main Street in the color red and users can filter it out if they only want well-paved roads.

So far I've looked into Mapbox which mentioned that basically every map works off of GeoJson and, from what I've read, it looks like GeoJSON is based on coordinates not types like "streets".